# Prove that two normed linear spaces are equivalent as metric spaces if and only if the norms are equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

We have the two norms $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$ on the vectorspace V. They're equivalent if there exists a $k>0$ and $K>0$ so that  $k\|\cdot\|_a\le\|\cdot\|_b\le$ K$\|\cdot\|_a$ for all $v\in V$.

I've proved this is an equivalence relation on the set of norms. I now have to prove, that $d_{\|\cdot\|_a}$ is equivalent to $d_{\|\cdot\|_b}$ if and only if $\|\cdot\|_a$ is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_b$.

I've already proven the "if"-statement, I just have to prove the "only if"-statement now, and I don't really have any ideas how to do it. I would appreciate a little help very much.

Comment: Previous comment removed due to updated wording. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this question makes sense. The only way I understand this is by assuming $d_{\|\cdots\|_a}(x,y)=\|x-y\|_a$. So this is a tautology. What did I miss?

Comment: @julien: I believe it is a simple argument, though not quite a tautology.  The metric $d_{||\cdot ||_a}$ is a (real) function of two arguments while the norm $||\cdot ||_a$ takes only a single argument, just as you understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of equivalent metrics is not given in the Question, and so let's work from a pretty basic notion of that, meaning [the identity map on $V$ is a homeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Equivalence_of_metrics) when metric $d_{||\cdot ||_a}$ is supplied for $V$ as the domain and metric $d_{||\cdot ||_b}$ for $V$ as the range.

For arbitrary metrics this notion of equivalence is too weak to conclude a "mutual coercivity" as desired here, so our argument will hinge on the fact that these two particular metrics are norm-derived.  [To illustrate the point](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75683/3111), consider the metric $d_e$ derived from the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and as alternative "truncated" metric:

$$ d_f(x,y) = \min \{ d_e(x,y), 1 \} $$

Even though the two metrics are equivalent in the sense of the identity map being a homeomorphism (or equivalently, in giving the same topology) on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there does not exist a constant $K$ not depending on $x,y$ such that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

$$ d_e(x,y) \le K\; d_f(x,y) $$

Let's cite [this previous MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53564/equivalent-metrics-iff-same-convergent-sequences) for the proposition that two metric topologies are equivalent if and only if they have the same convergent sequences.  Also let's simplify notation slightly, calling our norm-derived metrics:

$$ d_a(x,y) = ||x - y||_a $$
$$ d_b(x,y) = ||x - y||_b $$

**Easy direction:**  Assume norms $||\cdot ||_a$ and $||\cdot ||_b$ are equivalent on vector space $V$, i.e. there exist positive constants $k,K$ as described in the Question.  Then:

$$ k\; d_a(x,y) \le d_b(x,y) \le K\; d_a(x,y) \;\; \forall x,y \in V $$

From this pair of inequalities it is readily seen that a sequence $\{x_i\}$ converges with respect to one metric if and only if does so with respect to the other metric.  Given $\epsilon \gt 0$, if $d_b(x_i,y) \lt k\epsilon$ for all $i \gt M$, then $d_a(x_i,y) \lt \epsilon$ for the same $i \gt M$.  Similarly one shows the implication of convergence after exchanging metrics by replacing $k$ with $1/K$.

**Less easy direction:**  Assume the metric topologies induced by $d_a,d_b$ are equivalent.  We will show (by contradiction) that there exists $K \gt 0$ such that:

$$ d_b(x,y) \le K\; d_a(x,y) $$

and leave the existence of the constant $k$ in the other inequality as an exercise.  If no such constant $K$ exists, then for each integer $i \gt 0$ we can find $x_i$ such that $d_a(x_i,0) < 2^{-i}$ and $d_b(x_i,0) = 2^i$, using the translation invariance and scaling properties of any norm-derived metric.  Clearly ${x_i}$ converges to zero in the metric $d_a$, but the distances between points grow too rapidly for the same sequence to converge in the metric $d_b$, contradicting the equivalence of topologies.  That is, by the "reverse triangle inequality":

$$ d_b(x_i,x_{i+1}) \ge | d_b(x_{i+1},0) - d_b(x_i,0) | = 2^{i+1} - 2^i = 2^i $$

whereas in a convergent sequence the distances between consecutive terms must tend to zero.